# Giving an UIImage variable an Array element is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

I got this code and I can't seem to make `self.pickedImage` work when giving it an element of the array ( in the example I'm trying to give it the first one). It works fine if I just say:

```
self.PickedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal"];
```

so the problem is at

```
[self.arrayPersonal objectAtIndex:0]
```

and

```
[self.arrayWork objectAtIndex:0];
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
self.arrayPersonal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal1"], nil];
    self.arrayWork = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work1"], nil];
if(self.chosenCategory == 1) self.pickedImage = [self.arrayPersonal objectAtIndex:0];
if(self.chosenCategory == 2) self.pickedImage = [self.arrayWork objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: What is the problem, what are you getting from the array? what is PickedImage, post some code where you define it, is it a property?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "not working" ? Is self.pickedImage nil after assignment ?

Comment: And what does the arrays contain?

Comment: Yes, pickedImage is a UIImage property. @property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *pickedImage;

Comment: @kudoCC yes, if i say NSLog (@"%@", self.PickedImage ) it shows nothing.

Comment: @reecon I mentioned in the post: `self.arrayPersonal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal1"], nil];`                                                         
    `self.arrayWork = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work1"], nil];`

Comment: `NSLog(@"%d, %@, %@", self.choseCategory, self.arrayPersonal, self.arrayWork) ;` Please show us the result. Maybe self.choseCategory is neither 1 nor 2...

Comment: @KudoCC 2014-07-22 14:39:06.246 DiaryApp[1143:60b] 1, (null), (null)

Comment: You should define the `arrayPersonal` and `arrayWork` using @property (nonatomic, strong) arrayPersonal;

Comment: Note that, if `[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_personal"]`==nil, self.arrayPersonal will contain no objects, since it is NULL terminated. Same for `self.arrayWork` and `[UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_work"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you want to add uiimage object to an array !
try this

```
self.arrayPersonal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"icn_personal",@"icn_personal1", nil];
    self.arrayWork = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"icn_work.png",@"icn_work1", nil];
if(self.chosenCategory == 1) self.pickedImage = [self.arrayPersonal objectAtIndex:0];
if(self.chosenCategory == 2) self.pickedImage = [self.arrayWork objectAtIndex:0];
```

just make sure you are using png since you are not mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `weak` attribute in `arrayPersonal` and `arrayWork` property, the `NSArray` assigned to them will be released soon, and the two values will be nil.

Instead, Define `arrayPersonal` and `arrayWork` property with `strong` attribute.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) arrayPersonal;
@property (nonatomic, strong) arrayWork;
```